# Tor Browser Bundle for Windows without installer?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

I can't find a non-installer download for the browser bundle for Windows anymore.

I still see non-installers for Mac/Linux.

Did they remove it? Why??? I hate installers since you don't know if they put stuff into the registry or user folders. When you just extract an archive you know where the files goes, THAT'S what I want.

Anyone know if you can still get a non-installer Tor Browser bundle?

Answer (score 1):

You could always build on Onion Pi or just buy a router already loaded with it like PAPARouter  ( cheap: 100.00)
U can anonymize all your stuff then. Nothing the Feds love better than zero day exploits on the Windows browser bundle anyway

Comment: Off topic but maybe useful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the [download page](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en). Depending from your operating system (or the one your browser reports) you'll see the download button for Windows/Linux/Mac. Also at the [main download site](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en) there are links to all versions. Select the correct version and download it. At the moment the download link for windows points to https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/3.5.3/torbrowser-install-3.5.3_en-US.exe.

Comment: Which is the exact same installer I'm talking about. I don't want an installer. Just wondering why the hell they are forcing an installer on us all of a sudden.

Comment: Can.... Can you not read?

Answer (score 1):

Well this is not a zip but 7z can unzip this exe no problem (tried it) and then you can just move the "Start Tor Browser.exe" to the "$_OUTDIR" folder and you have in effect the same deal without having to execute the file.

Comment: Currently it's not a 7z archive anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Peter:  Your concerns are understandable, since on the Windows platform, "installer" programs historically have been used to keep many kinds of mischief hidden from the user that invokes them - but in this case, it's more like a self-extracting ZIP file, and made like that for the benefit of those who wouldn't know what to do with the file otherwise.  As user1452 says, you can always use a program like 7-Zip to do the extracting for you, but if you don't trust the makers of Tor themselves to create a working copy of Tor on your system without it harming your system or leaving evidence of Tor's existence buried somewhere, then perhaps you're too paranoid to use the Internet in any form.

Comment: I disagree. The file could be changed, or a request replacement could occur, replacing the file. It should be run in a sandbox or vm (also a sandbox), if you want the most security. Requiring installation means if it's replaced (either on the server or in the middle of the download), then you're SOL.

Comment: @JVE999, the file is merely packaged in a way that allows users to double-click on the file to unpack it - which uses facilities built into Windows that are, confusingly, collectively referred to as the "Windows installer".  Also, as much as many other program suppliers try to conflate the two, "download" and "install" are two separate and distinct operations.  In the case of Tor, there's no reason to be on the Internet at all while you "run" the "installer" file.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why they force using installer as well, it's frustrating. And installer is not 7z SFX anymore. So the only option is to install the app from distr and pack it yourself. I also found [repo with portable bundle](https://gareth.flowers/tor-browser-portable/) but IDK how trustworthy it is.

Comment: unfortunately not updated for 3y, but the finding is good.

Answer (score 0):

Current as of writing this - *directory browsing* is turned on so you can go to https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/ and look through it yourself.

- https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/8.5.4/tor-win64-0.4.0.5.zip gets you just the tor.exe / tor-gencert.exe binaries + needed libraries
- https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/8.5.4/torbrowser-install-8.5.4_en-US.exe is the installer, but 7-zip can open it up just fine. Running "firefox.exe" from the unpacked files will prompt you to connect to the Tor network and start the Tor Browser.